# Как предотвратить скрытие Modal при отправке, если в форме есть ошибка? (Django, js)

Tags: javascript, django

При регистрации выскакивает модальное окно. После отправки post-запроса пользователя отправляет по адресу ..registrate/, где происходит обработка заброса через вью RegisterView. Однако после этого перенаправления модальное окно закрывается вне зависимости от того были ли ошибки или нет.
**Как оставить открытым модальное окно, если валидация не прошла?**

Про такое решение `{% if form.errors %}modal-active{% endif %}` я прочитал. Оно не помогает. У меня пустое окно открывается.
Если `<div class="header__slide-modal-window" id="empty-pic" data-window></div>` заменить на
`<div class="header__slide-modal-window" id="empty-pic" data-window="{% if form.errors %}2{% endif %}"></div>`
то модальное окно также остается открытым, но оно пустое.

Код HTML

```
        <!--  Шаблон модального окна  -->
        <div class="swiper-section-modal {% if form.errors %}modal-active{% endif %}" data-modal>
          <div class="swiper-section-modal__content">
            <div class="swiper-section-modal__content-right">
              <button class="close btn-reset"></button>
              <div class="header__slide-modal-window" id="empty-pic" data-window></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
...
{% if not request.user.is_authenticated %}
            <button class="header__top-widgets-link swiper-slide btn-reset">
              Login
              <div class="header__slide-modal-content" id="1" data-content="1">
                <h2 class="header__slide-modal-content-title title">Login</h2>
                <p class="header__slide-modal-content-name">New to site? <a id="pop_signup" href="">Create an Account</a></p>
                <form class="header__slide-modal-content-login-form" method="post" action="{% url 'login' %}">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                  <input type="text" class="login-username" autofocus="true" required="true" placeholder="Username" name="username" />
                  <input type="password" class="login-password" required="true" placeholder="Password" name="password" />
                  <input type="submit" name="Login" value="Login" class="btn btn-reset" />
                </form>
                <a href="{% url 'restore_password' %}" class="login-forgot-pass">Lost password?</a>
              </div>
            </button>
            <button class="header__top-widgets-link swiper-slide btn-reset">
              Register
              <div class="header__slide-modal-content" id="2" data-content="2">
                <h2 class="header__slide-modal-content-title title">Register</h2>
                <p class="header__slide-modal-content-name">Already have an account? <a id="pop_login" href="">Login</a></p>
                <form class="header__slide-modal-content-register-form" method="post" action="{% url 'register' %}">
                  {% csrf_token %}
                  {% for f in form %}
                  <p><label class="login-username" for="{{ f.id_for_label }}">{{f.label}}:</label>{{ f }}</p>
                  <div class="">{{ f.errors }}</div>
                  {% endfor %}
                  <input type="submit" name="Register" value="Register" class="btn btn-reset" />
                </form>                
              </div>
            </button>
```

скрипт js

```
(() => {
    let swiperSlides = document.querySelector(".header__container").querySelectorAll(".swiper-slide");
    let modal = document.querySelector(".swiper-section-modal");
    let modalBtn = modal.querySelector(".close");
    let html = document.documentElement;
    //сохраним текущую прокрутку:
    console.log(swiperSlides[0])
    var scrollPosition = swiperSlides[0].getBoundingClientRect().top;
    console.log(scrollPosition)

    swiperSlides.forEach(el => {
    el.addEventListener("click", function() {
        let img = this.querySelector("img");
        let content = this.querySelector("div");
        let name = content.getAttribute("data-content");
        let scrollPosition = window.pageYOffset;
        var cont_div1 = document.getElementById(name);
        var cont_div2 = document.getElementById("empty-pic");
        cont_div2.innerHTML = cont_div1.innerHTML;
        animation(modal, "modal-active", "play");
        modal.querySelector(".header__slide-modal-window").setAttribute("data-window", name);
    
        //блокировка страницы
        window.scrollTo(0, scrollPosition);
        html.classList.add("hystmodal__opened");

    })
    })

    modalBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    animation(modal, "modal-active", "reverse");
    //разблокировка страницы
    html.classList.remove("hystmodal__opened");
    console.log(scrollPosition);
    window.scrollTo(0, scrollPosition);
    });

    window.onclick = function (event) {
    if (event.target.hasAttribute('data-modal')) {
        animation(modal, "modal-active", "reverse");
        event.target.style.display = "none";
        //разблокировка страницы
        html.classList.remove("hystmodal__opened");
        window.scrollTo(0, scrollPosition);
    }
    };


    function animation(el, Class, flag) {
    if (flag === "play") {
        el.style.display = "flex";
        setTimeout(function() {
        el.classList.add(Class);
        }, 50)
    } else if (flag === "reverse") {
        el.classList.remove(Class);
        setTimeout(function() {
        el.style.display = "none";
        }, 700)
    }
    };
    
})();
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('restore_password/', WebPasswordResetView.as_view(), name='restore_password'),
    path('register/', RegisterView.as_view(), name='register'),
]
```

view.py

```
class BaseView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'app_products/index.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['profile'] = Profile.objects.filter(user_id=self.request.user.id).first()
        context['form'] = ExtendedRegisterForm()
        return context


class RegisterView(CreateView):
    """ Представление для регистрации """
    form_class = ExtendedRegisterForm
    template_name = 'app_products/index.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        user = form.save()
        login(self.request, user)
        print(form.cleaned_data.get('username'))
        Profile.objects.create(
            user=user,
            slug=form.cleaned_data.get('username'),
            email=form.cleaned_data.get('email'),
        )
        return redirect('/')
```

[image: Сама форма (модальное окно)]
[! То, что я получаю после отправки с ошибками][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdzUM.png)

[1]: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qw4Ql.png][2]][2]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qw4Ql.png%5D%5B2%5D%5D%5B2%5D)